# How can I execute a particular function on every route except one in sammy.js

Tags: routes, sammy.js

I have few routes in my application:

```
Sammy(function() {
    this.get('#!foo', function(){
        ...
    });

    this.get('#!bar', function(){
        ...
    });

    ... and so on...

    this.get('#!special', function(){
        ...
    })
}).run();
```

And I have a function `initialize();` which has no connection to sammy if I hit any of the routes except of `#!special`. Of course I can copy it each of my routes except the `special` (which will work, but will be kind of stupid). Is there a way to achieve this?

P.S. or if you do not know how to do this, is there a way to run the function on each route hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps Sammy's [.before](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.4/all#Sammy.Application-before) method would work for you?

Here's some sample (untested) code that could do what you want:

```
this.before({except: {path: '#!special'}}, function() {
    initialize();
});
```

The `.before()` method basically allows you to do some callback before every route, but also allows you to filter out certain routes (or do the opposite and whitelist certain routes).